# Okami HD camera controls

Tags: ps3, okami, okami-hd

I started playing Okami HD for PS3, and there is an option to change the camera controls where you can invert the X or Y axis, or both. I tried changing it and then go into the game, but it's still the same. I then quit the game (by exiting it entirely, there is no option to go back to the main menu) and go into options again, and the setting is back on "Normal," like it didn't save. Upon changing the setting and hitting back I have to confirm a dialogue saying the setting will be changed, so I'm fairly sure it should be changing. Does this feature actually work? Am I doing something wrong? This is using the normal PS3 controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. First of all, your control settings are only applied when starting a new game, *not* when you load a saved game. That's incredibly annoying because you have to sit through a 20 minute unskippable cutscene when starting a game... Second, this game's version of "normal" and "inverted" are actually the opposite of what I would expect them to be. I normally play games with Y axis inverted and X axis normal. I had to set this game to Y normal and X inverted to get it how I want.